# php call function without brackets

Tags: php-7

I have a simple function, I call it by `ABCfunction();` no arguments, nothing.
Is it possible to call it (somehow) with no brackets? Just `ABCfunction` - to have just as simple call as that?

Comment: @holly-plyler answered your question, but perhaps if we had some idea of the context of why you wanna to this we could help ya with an alternative approach?

Comment: I just want to avoid () - that's all

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you're asking if you can call the function like this.

function

instead of like this:

funcion();

The answer is no, even though you're not technically passing anything to the function, those brackets are still needed so that the computer knows that it is a function. Otherwise it could be a variable etc.(In functional programming sometimes you do not need brackets under certain situations, but in those cases the function is a variable.)

Comment: Yes, I know. I am asking if it can be f.e. replaced like AAfunction and somehow it will be changed for function() by interpreter or so